How to derive 15 minute interval name from TimeKey
I need to derive 15 minutes interval number and 15 minute interval name from TimeKey I have.
please note I am giving random examples just to describe the request.
To explain in words 00:00:00 interval will be 1 and 00:00-00:14 will be interval name
and 23:59:59 interval will be 96 and interval name is 23:45-23:59
Sale:



ID
TimeKey




1
00:00:00


2
01:15:00


3
04:30:00


4
05:15:00



Expected output:



ID
TimeKey
15 Minute Interval Number
15 Minute Interval Name




1
00:00:00
1
00:00-00:14


2
01:15:00
6
01:15-01:29


3
04:30:00
19
04:30-04:44


4
05:15:00
22
05:15-05:29



Please advice how to do this
Thanks in advance

Which DBMS are you using? And what is the TimeKey column's data type? Have you tried anything yourself? This seems to be some math. Dividing the minutes since midnight by 15 mainly.

Microsoft SQL Server 2019, TimeKey data type is time(0), not null. I have tried datediff(minute,0,TimeKey) / 15 +1 as 15MinutesIntervalNumber and need suggestions on 15MinutesIntervalName. Thank you

For the interval, you can use datediff(minute, 0, D) % 1440 / 15 + 1 as [15MinutesIntervalNumber]. The % 1440 modulo operation trims the datediff minutes to just those since midnight (instead on minutes since 1900-01-01). From there, you should be able to use date arithmetic to calculate st,art and end times, format them as strings, and concatenate the parts together for your interval name.

Hint: If you wrap the IntervalNumber calculation up in a CROSS APPLY (SELECT ... AS IntervalNumber) I, you can then reference that value in other calculations like DATEADD(minute, 15 * I.IntervalNumber - 15, '00:00'). The CONVERT(CHAR(5), timevalue, 14) will give you an "HH:MM" formatted result. The CONCAT() function or just + can be used to join the parts together. (tVMEe0bK)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

T N, thank you for the hint.

For your consideration
WITH TimeKey(D) AS
(
SELECT { ts '2011-08-29 00:00:00.000' } UNION ALL
SELECT { ts '2011-08-28 00:00:00.000' } UNION ALL
SELECT { ts '2011-08-29 01:29:00.000' }
)
SELECT [15 Minute Interval] =  1 + ((DATEDIFF(ms, 0,
                 DATEADD(Day, 0 - DATEDIFF(Day, 0, D), D)) ) / 1000 / 60) / 15
FROM TimeKey  



Why base calculations on the difference in milliseconds?

Just showing off.
